# Investigate the existence of the tangent plane

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

We consider the function $f(x,y)=y(x(y^2-1))^{\frac{1}{3}}$, I want to find, if there exists, the tangent plane at the function in $(0,1)$.
The existence, is linke to the differentiability of the function in $(0,1)$. After the observation that the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$ and $y$ in $(0,1)$ are $0$, I tried to prove the differentiability by using the definition.
$$ \lim_{(h,k) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{f(h,1+k)-f(0,1)-f_x(0,1)h-f(0,1)k}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}= \lim_{(h,k) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{(1+k)(hk(k+2))^{\frac{1}{3}}}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}= \lim_{(h,k) \rightarrow (0,0)} (1+k)(\frac{h^2k^2(2+k)^2}{(h^2+k^2)^3})^{\frac{1}{6}}$$
So, the limit is zero if and only if $\lim_{(h,k) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{h^2k^2}{(h^2+k^2)^3}=0$. But by using polar coordinate, I show that the limit is $+ \infty$ or don't exists. This is right?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

More easy is to take $h=k$ and from $\lim_{(h,k) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{h^2k^2}{(h^2+k^2)^3}$ obtain $\lim\limits_{h \to 0}\frac{h^4}{8h^6}=+\infty$. So main conclusion is right  - limit not exist.